# given a number N and 2 arrays A and B of sorted order of size N, print the common elements.If it is not found print -1

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

please check my error in my code, my code get 2 array and then concat these two array, get this array to object and turn it to array again, sort it and return most common element.

```
function plus() {
    let A = document.getElementById('array1').value;
    let B = document.getElementById('array2').value;
    let A1 = A.split(/\s+/g);
    let B1 = B.split(/\s+/g);
    let C = A1.concat(B1);
    let obj = {};
    for (let i=0; i<C.length; i++) {
        if (obj[C[i].toString()] === undefined) {
            obj[C[i].toString()] = 1;
        }
        else {
            obj[C[i].toString()]++;
        }
    }
    let arr = [];
    for (let key in obj) {
        arr.push({
            number: key,
            repeat: obj[key]
        })
    }
    arr.sort(function (a,b) {
            return b.repeat - a.repeat;
        }
    );
    if (arr[0].repeat == arr[1].repeat) {
        console.log('-1');
    }
    else {
        console.log(arr[0].number);

    }


    }
```

Comment: Please add sample input and required output.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Are the values in each array unique? Also there are better ways to check if an element in one array exists in another. Map if you need to count the number of things or Set if you just need to know the existence of the element.

Comment: Your title and description describe two different operations. Do you want to find the common elements between the arrays? Or do you want to find the most common element in both arrays?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the issue, you're trying to get the mutual elements in 2 arrays. Here's how I'd do it.

```
array1 = ["1","2","3"]
array2 = ["2","3","4"]
resultsArray = []

array1.map(element => array2.includes(element) ? resultsArray.push(element) : null)

if(resultsArray.length==0){
    console.log("-1")
}else{
    console.log(resultsArray)
    console.log(resultsArray.length)
}
```

or if you want something simpler

```
array1 = ["1","2","3"]
array2 = ["2","3","4"]
resultsArray = []


for(let i = array1.length - 1 ; i>=0 ; i--){
     if(array2.includes(array1[i]){
          resultsArray.push(array1[i])
     }
}

if(resultsArray.length==0){
    console.log("-1")
}else{
    console.log(resultsArray)
    console.log(resultsArray.length)
}
```

Feel free to comment any questions...